# Jscrollpane problem

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

There's probably a much better way to do this, but I'm a bit new to javascript/jquery.
I'm trying to set up a webform inside a scrollpane using jscrollpane.
The form contains several textareas, which are acting as rich text editors using tinymce.
Having tried a whole bunch of things to make the whole thing work in chrome, firefox and IE, I'm getting close by initialising the scrollpane like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('.flexcroll').jScrollPane(
 {
       verticalDragMinHeight: 100,
  verticalDragMaxHeight: 100,
  autoReinitialise: true,
  autoReinitialiseDelay: 3000
 });
 });
</script>
```

I've used the autoReinitialise because what was happening was that the scrollpane was being applied before the RTE controls were being applied to the textareas. When the controls were applied, the bottom of the form was being pushed off the bottom of the pane. The autoReinitialise fixes this in IE and Chrome, but there is a visible 'jump' every time it reinitialises in Firefox.

I either need to be able to figure out how to reinitialise in Firefox without seeing this jump, or I need to keep the jscrollpane function from applying until after the controls have been added to the RTE textareas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What version of jScrollPane are you using? There shouldn't be any jumps when it re-initialises, if you can duplicate this on the latest version (beta9) then please let me know as it may be a bug that needs fixing.

Looking at the TinyMCE documentation it looks like there is an "oninit" callback which executes "when all editor instances have finished their initialization". You could try initialising (or manually re-initialising) jScrollPane inside this callback.

More information:
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:oninit

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I had been using beta6, but I've just replaced it with beta9, and I'm still seeing the same behaviour. However, with beta6, the jump happened every 3 seconds until the window was closed; with beta9, it jumps every 3 seconds until the scrollbar is moved. After the scrollbar is moved, it's fine.

I'll have a look at that oninit callback and see if i can figure it out.

Cheers again, and let me know if you need any more detail on that bug.

Comment: As for using the oninit callback, thanks! I've removed the autoreinitailise behaviour and It's working every time in chrome and IE, but only some of the time in Firefox. Have you ever come across something like this? I would've assumed the callback would happen at the same time across all browsers, no?

Forgive me again for being a bit new to all this...

Comment: Re. the jump - if you can put together a demo page showing the problem (preferably on jsfiddle.net ) and report an issue on https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/issues with a link to the example I will investigate. Please include version of browser and OS you are seeing.

Comment: Re. the oninit - do you mean that the callback itself isn't firing in Firefox? How are you seeing this? If it is the case then the problem is in TinyMCE... If the callback is happening but jScrollPane isn't working then please clarify and add a URL showing the problem...

Comment: I'm not sure if the callback is firing on the occassions that I get the incomplete content. I suppose it must be a TinyMCE thing - I'll see if I can find something on their forums.
I'll get a demo page put together later on this evening and I'll let you know.

Cheers again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use window.load rather than document.ready, I fixed the firefox issue using this, firefox supposedly does this weird cashing and stuff, and makes this to happen....